# How to tell use relevant registered MySession class by name

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container, aspnetboilerplate

I have project created from [Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/)

I have MySession class that will be used from MvcControllers and WebApi Controllers.

In MySession has two derived classes:

MySessionMvc:

```
 public override string UserId {
  get {

   return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId();
  }
 }
```

and

MySessionWebApi:

```
 public override string UserId {
  get {

   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UserId"];
  }
 }
```

I register both classes:

```
IocManager.RegisterIfNot<IMySession, MySessionMvc>(DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton, "MyNamespace.MySessionMvc");

IocManager.RegisterIfNot<IMySession, MySessionWebApi>(DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton, "MyNamespace.MySessionWebApi");
```

Now it is time to tell the which MySession derived class will be used for relevant controller.

<s>A "horrible" solution, inject container to each controller and use it</s>
I see now I can easily inject it to my controller

```
protected MyBaseController(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    MySession = container.Resolve<IMySession> "MyNamespace.MySessionWebApi");
}
```

And at controller level I achieve my goal.

On the other hand I need to tell Auditing interceptor tell same dependency resolve. This interceptor takes UserId info from MySession.

```
namespace My.Auditing
{
    internal class AuditingInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public IMySession MySession { get; set; }

    }
}
```

How can I proceed that I can correctly resolve the relevant MySession at interceptor level?

Comment: The last sentence doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @aaron Please see my edit, I hope my progress and addition is more clear now

Comment: How is your interceptor registered? One approach would be to use scoped components and ensure both the interceptor and controller belong to the same scope.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt Could you point me a QA or example about `scoped component`

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt something like [this](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
    Component.For<MySessionWebApi>().LifestylePerWebRequest(), Component.For<MySessionMvc>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
    Component.For<IMySession>().UsingFactoryMethod((k, c) => this.MySessionFactory(k)).LifestylePerWebRequest().IsDefault());


 private IMySession MySessionFactory(IKernel kernel)
{
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request == null)
        {
            return (IMySession)kernel.Resolve<MySessionMvc>();  

        }
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Contains("/api/"))
        {
            return (IMySession)kernel.Resolve<MySessionWebApi>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (IMySession)kernel.Resolve<MySessionMvc>();
        } 
}
```

That's all folks!

Comment: @aaron So my question was confusing and not accurate? since answer is obvious and found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32067711/492258)